# how to convert Hindi numbers ( २०७४) to numeric value in c#?

Tags: c#, hindi, devanagari

I have a large group of Hindi numbers which i want to convert into numeric values but i don't know how to convert them . Please suggest me appropriate way to achieve this.
**Note** Please don't suggest me replace method.

eg. convert this number  २०७४ to equivalent to 2074.

Comment: *Please don't suggest me replace method.* So what do you expect then? If we don't replace them, how would we convert them?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Hindi culture, then `int.Parse` ?

Comment: Actually i don't know in advance what the number would be, so i want general solution to achieve this. could you please explain how would you do this?

Comment: Are those characters just different glyphs for 0-9? Meaning, *could* you do it with a simple replacement? Or is it a different numeric system altogether?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve right now. Can you show what you have got already?

Comment: I think the Replace method would be simpler and fastest solution and i'm not sure what issue you are facing using replace method. You just have to create a list with 10 items (0 to 9).

Comment: You need to tell us why you can't make do with "the replace method" as it seems this would be pretty straightforward to do. According to [the wikipedia page](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A5%AA) which shows a table for the numbers it seems they're just different symbols for `0-9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after but **be aware that this code is written by someone who doesn't speak Hindi, read Hindi or *know* Hindi**.

I found the digits on [the wikipedia page](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A5%AA) but I **absolutely have no idea what I'm doing**.

The google page (which I found by just googling for the individual digits from the original string in the question) seems to indicate the following:

- The digits for 0-9 are `०१२३४५६७८९`

  - I clicked on a link and used the last character of the url as the digit
  - Note that 4 had to be gotten as the second digit of 14, and there seems to be a disambiguity suffix on that link as well
- They have unicode code points ranging from 2406 through 2415, in that order
- The double digits numbers follow the system to a tee, so it seems to be just a 10-digit numeric system using different code points

  - But note that there are far too few examples for me to be absolutely certain this holds true for all numbers

If anyone pokes hole in this answer I will take it down but feel free to grab all the code from it first if you think it can be improved.

Also bear in mind that the OP **explicitly** asked for a non-replace method. The whole thing can probably be written in a oneliner with that but since that doesn't seem to be an acceptable answer then here we are.

With all that said, here's a non-string-replace version that mimicks basic numeric parsing using different symbols:

**Note:** There's about 7 tons of error-handling that isn't present here, such as empty strings, etc.

```
public static bool TryParseHindiToInt32(string text, out int value)
{
    const int codePointForZero = 2406;
    const int codePointForNine = codePointForZero + 9;

    int sign = +1;

    int index = 0;
    if (index < text.Length && text[index] == '-') // todo: hindi minus?
    {
        index++;
        sign = -1;
    }

    value = 0;
    while (index < text.Length)
    {
        char c = text[index];
        if (c < codePointForZero || c > codePointForNine)
        {
            value = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if ((uint)value > 214748364u)
        {
            value = 0;
            return false;
        }

        value *= 10;
        value += (c - codePointForZero);
        index++;
    }

    value *= sign;
    return true;
}
```

Test:

```
string digits = "२०७४";
TryParseHindiToInt32(digits, out int i);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Outputs:

```
2074
```

Comment: thanks for replying me